# substracting balance before executing transfer with msg.sender global in Solidity

Tags: solidity

During my course in solidity in withrdrawal patterns i came accross the following problem as a complete noob in programming. While writing the below withdraw function with msg.sender , the instructor during the solution of the exercise places the substracted amount before the execution of the transfer. Is this crucial to the code or it can be run with the following order? Thank you.

```
function withdrawFunds(uint amount) public payable returns (bool success) {
    require(balance[msg.sender] >= amount);
    msg.sender.transfer(amount);
    balance[msg.sender] -= amount;
    return success;
}
```

expected the `msg.sender.transfer(amount)` to precede the substraction of the amount `balance[msg.sender] -= amount` in the lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

The order set in this question is vulnerable to the [reentrancy](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-107) attack vector.

If the `msg.sender` is a contract, they can invoke your `withdrawFunds()` from their `receive()` function (executed upon receiving ETH through the `.transfer()` function) before the `amount` is subtracted.

So, this way, the attacker is able to recursively sweep all funds from the contract.

Example:

1. The contract holds 2 ETH, while `balance[msg.sender]` is just 1 ETH (and the remaining 1 ETH is recorded to belong to some other address).
2. The attacker contract (`msg.sender`) invokes the `withdrawFunds()` function specifying to withdraw 1 ETH. Which passes the `require()` condition, as they have the 1 ETH recorded.
3. Upon receiving 1 ETH from the `transfer()` function, their `receive()` function invokes the `withdrawFunds()` again.
4. Having not updated the `balance` yet, the `require()` condition passes again, and the attacker receives another 1 ETH.
5. As the vulnerable contract is empty now, the attacker breaks the recursion, and finally the `balance[msg.sender]` is updated just once by subtracting the 1 ETH that they originally requested to withdraw. Score: vulnerable contract 0 ETH, attacker 2 ETH.